# Mapbox not displaying maps after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox on my webpage to display maps. Initially, when I access the page, the map works correctly. However, when I refresh the page, the map is not displayed as expected. Instead, it shows a broken image icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lyRR.png)

I'm using the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="latitude" class="form-label">Latitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control" placeholder="Latitude" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="longitude" class="form-label">Longitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitude" aria-describedby="helpId">
        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the HTML code, I have a map container div with the id "map" and appropriate dimensions. I'm also using the Mapbox GL CSS and JavaScript dependencies by including the following links:

```
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
```

I have the following code that includes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

```
  var latitude = 0;
  var longitude = 0;
  let mapInitialized = false; // Flag variable to track map initialization

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      showPosition(position);
      console.log("Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);
      initMap(latitude, longitude);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }

  function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtZGVlbmFzZW5nIiwiYSI6ImNsZXRuZGhxNjBnOW4zc3BmNGVka3dzNzEifQ.OxY8nCfd2EFxqgX6D-yi7Q';

    if (mapInitialized) {
      return; // Map already initialized, exit the function
    }

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [longitude, latitude],
      zoom: 10
    });

    mapInitialized = true;

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
      positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      },
      trackUserLocation: true
    }));
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.ScaleControl());

    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
      draggable: true
    })
    .setLngLat([longitude, latitude])
    .addTo(map);

    marker.on('dragend', function() {
      var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
      console.log('Longitude:', lngLat.lng);
      console.log('Latitude:', lngLat.lat);
    });

    marker.on('dragend', function() {
      var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
      document.getElementById('latitude').value = lngLat.lat;
      document.getElementById('longitude').value = lngLat.lng;
    });

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
      offset: 25
    })
    .setLngLat([longitude, latitude])
    .setHTML("<h3>Marker Label</h3><p>Location: " + marker.getLngLat().toString() + "</p>")
    .addTo(map);

    marker.setPopup(popup);
  }
```

In the JavaScript code, I'm initializing the map using the Mapbox GL JS library. I retrieve the user's geolocation and center the map accordingly. Additionally, I add controls for navigation, geolocation, and scale to the map. I also include a draggable marker with a popup.

Despite all these efforts, when I refresh the page, the map is not displayed. Instead, I see a broken image icon. I have checked that the necessary dependencies are included and the access token is valid. I'm unable to identify the issue causing the map to not display after a page refresh.

Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!